# Best method to share eventemitter2 globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, eventemitter

I'm not new to programming, but new to NodeJS. I have a rather complex project that is now several modules deep, of course all rooted in app.js, similar to the following map:

```
App.js
    requires('Module_a')
    requires('Module_b')
    requires('EventEmitter2');


Module_a.js
    requires('Module_a1');
    requires('Module_a2');

Module_b.js
    requires('Module_b1');
    requires('Module_b2');
```

I want events generated in Module_a2 to be visible up at app.js and all the way down to Module_b2, and b2 events visible in a2, and so on. How best do I make the same instance of EventEmitter globally visible to all the modules?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It is best not to globalize it, but rather to require your `Events` module wherever needed. See here for  a simple solution: [How do you share an EventEmitter in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659266/how-do-you-share-an-eventemitter-in-node-js)